# php $_POST using $$ call

Tags: php, variables, post

I'm aware that the following piece of code is possible in php:

```
$dog = 'Woof!';
$cat = 'Miauw!';
$animal = 'dog';
var_dump($$animal);
```

Output: 'Woof!'

Of course this is a simplified example of my actual code, nonetheless you get the idea.
Now I can't seem to get the `$_POST` variable to act the same way.

Example:

```
$method = '_POST';
$$method['password'] = array();
// In the end i would want this piece of code above to do what i typed below
$_POST['password'] = array();
```

Output: 'Notice: Undefined variable: _POST'

So does this mean it is not possible to call $_POST this way or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Why would you access $_POST via variable variable names? What do you get when you do var_dump($$method)?

Comment: complete shot in the dark, but try ${$method}['password']. I'm wondering if the array is the problem and not the variable.

Comment: @Michael this allows you to decentralize the method you are using instead of using a bunch of conditionals.

Comment: Using the `$$` syntax is bad news. It's not quite as bad a `eval()` but it's a pretty close second. Please try to avoid it -- there's always a better solution than this.

Comment: @Spudley what do you suggest?

Comment: @nalroff - your comment is way too vague. Decentralize the method of doing what exactly? All request variables are stored in $_REQUEST, it's a superglobal and it's available in any function, any class, any namespace. If you are creating copies and inflating memory, there has to be a good reason. Saying it "decentralizes" can mean anything, so if it's not a prob - you might want to clarify what you mean with examples and pros / cons of such approach. Otherwise, I'll be inclined to think that variable variable names are bad if created from $_GET / $_POST (register_globals anyone?).

Comment: @Michael i think what nalroff means with his comment is that i won't have to use conditionals like `if ($method == '_POST') { $_POST['password'] = array() }`. So using variable variables decentralizes the process in a sense, thus avoiding the conditionals.

Comment: @lugte - if it's always going to be `$_POST` or `$_GET`, you could either just use `$_REQUEST` (which contains them both), or have a short `if()` block to determine which one to use. The `$$` syntax is bad because it introduces security issues (in the same way as `eval()`), and also it prevents the interpreter from being able to perform some optimisations, so it can cause your code to run slower.

Comment: @lugte - why would you have to know the method? If you have data being sent to your page via _GET or _POST, you don't have to know the method since both _GET and _POST are mapped to $_REQUEST. You don't need the conditional at all, and I still see no reason why to shoot your own leg by using this approach that can create so many security holes.

Comment: @Michael because $_REQUEST is a different variable than $_GET and $_POST, it is treated as such in PHP -- modifying $_GET or $_POST elements at runtime will not affect the elements in $_REQUEST, nor vice versa. So this means that if i want to add something to $_REQUEST and then later want to retrieve it using $_POST, i will not get the values i need since it will not be automatically be added to $_POST. Using $GLOBALS for example will resolve this issue. And i'm not sure using $GLOBALS will result in any security issues, but i could be mistaken of course.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong, you shouldn't be touching $_POST, $_GET or $_REQUEST in the first place, but who am I to tell you what's right or wrong ;) trial and error ftw.

Comment: I'm not trying to be stubborn or anything, i'm just not really convinced yet. So why would you recommend not to touch $_POST for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined by the other answers, not even the superglobals are real globals in PHP. They need to be specifically imported into the local scope dict to be accessible with variable variables.

If you really only want to access $_POST and $_GET or $_REQUEST, then the explicit syntax would be however:

```
$GLOBALS[$method]['password'] = array();
```

Answer (score 5):

From [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

> Note: Variable variables Superglobals
>   cannot be used as variable variables
>   inside functions or class methods.

Comment: In his example $method is no longer a variable variable, it's a copy of the $_POST array and therefore no longer a super-global.

Comment: @Evert $method is indeed not a super-global, but Charles is still right, because in the end i do try to call the super-global $_POST through variable variables using $method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$$method['password'] = array();
```

is evaluated as:

```
${$method['password']} = array();
```

P.S.: You might be better off not doing this. Variable variables are confusing and considered a bit of a bad practice.

Comment: In my example, i would want `${$method}['password']` instead of `${$method['password']}`, if wat Charles' answered wouldn't have been true.